# jQuery - Append HTML more than once without repeating code?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to append some HTML to a div multiple times.

**Here's how I'm currently doing it:** http://jsfiddle.net/9m1cfL4u/

I want to append it 4 times in total, this method works perfectly fine but is there a tidier way to do this than calling the same append every time?  It looks messy and "un-proper" to me!

Thanks for any help!

```
$('.banner').append('<div class="content"></div>');
$('.banner').append('<div class="content"></div>');
$('.banner').append('<div class="content"></div>');
$('.banner').append('<div class="content"></div>');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `for` loop should suffice.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/q8tvr2fv/)

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    $('.banner').append('<div class="content"></div>');
}
```

..and without jQuery:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/yjLa57ce/)

```
var banner = document.querySelector('.banner'),
    content;

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    content = document.createElement('div');
    content.className += 'content';
    banner.appendChild(content);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And little bit fancier way of doing same thing.

```js
    $.fn.repeatTimes = function(times, cb) {
      for(var time = 1;time <= times; time += 1) {
        cb.call(this, time);
      }
      return this;
    }

    $(function(){
  
      $('.banner').repeatTimes(4, function(time) {
          this.append('<div class="content">this is ' + time + ' time</div>');
      });
    });
```

```html
<div class="banner"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```